# What are the most common first names of users on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, display-names, real-name

I am curious about what the most common first names are on Stack Overflow. I wondered if there was a BigQuery I could write to accomplish answering this question, but it doesn't seem feasible.

Does someone have insight as to the most common first names of users on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'd suspect _John_ and/or _Jane_ :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean by first name 'the first part of their display name' (we don't know their real first names of course), [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1079793/most-common-first-names) tells you it's John (as @πάνταῥεῖ suspected), closely followed by David:

[image]

Note that this doesn't take into account names like JohnDoe, because it has no space. Splitting Pascal Case words is a lot harder, but maybe there's a SQL wizard who can do better than me.

Comment: Interesting, I suspected _John_ or _Jane_ because explicitely taking _JohnDoe_ and _JaneDoe_ into account.

Comment: Would be nice if you could apply a derivate query putting that (ending with _Doe_) into account. ;-)

Comment: Well, I doubt the *real* first name of those users would be John or Jane...

Comment: Nice, I’m in third place.